# Validate that match can't be empty

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint, static-analysis, null-check

Is it possible that javascript linter will tell if regex will allways produce nonempty match?

```
s.match(/\w*/)[0]           // valid
s.match(/\w+/)[0]           // invalid
s.match(/id(\d{7})/)[1]     // invalid
s.match(/id(\d{7})|$/)[1]   // valid
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/837687/178988)

Answer (score 1):

No, eslint cannot analyze code like this at least out of the box.

> Code linting is a type of static analysis that is frequently used to find problematic patterns or code that doesn’t adhere to certain style guidelines.

https://eslint.org/docs/about/

Maybe you could write a plugin to validate those cases.

Comment: Is it possible to validate such thing for any regex? Or specified problem is equal to [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)?